# Why i can not trigger the jquery function?

Tags: javascript

This is a button to close the click but it fail and not work. I would like to know what is the tab ID since i did not think i assign one when i create a tab.

Thank you.

This is my attempt

js

```
$("#closeTab").click(function() {
window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('close','Create List');
});
```

html

```
<input type="button" id="closeTab" value="Cancel" class="submit"/>
```

**I found my js code is working** but the button can not trigger it? Why? thank you

latest try:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#addlist").validate();
}); 


$(function(){
  $("#closeTab").click(function() {
    window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('close','Create List');
  });
});

</script>
```

It still doesn't work so i think it is because the upper function ? How to fix this?

================================================================================
Also, are **there any ways to clear my session in using this jquery function** (what should i add for instance)?**Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript, you have to delay the execution of certain functions (like event handlers) until the page loads fully. Otherwise, it is attempting to bind a function to an element that doesn't yet exist. With jQuery, you can pass a function to jQuery to be executed on page load very easily like this:

```
$(function(){ /* code goes here */ });
```

So to use this with your code, you would do this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#closeTab").click(function() {
    window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('close','Create List');
  });
});
```

This way, when the jQuery attempts to bind the function to #closeTab, it happens after the page has loaded (and after #closeTab exists).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any errors in the console?

Do you include jQuery before that click binding?

Try changing the `window.parent....` to `alert('clicked!');` and make sure you're actually getting there.

Also, make sure the click binding is inside of a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A script can close only the windows it creates. It cannot close the tab which it didn't create.

To rephrase, cannot close tab only if unless but when created tab by script which is same that close window.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the form is submitted and the browser navigates to another URL before the code could run? Try replacing `function()` with `function(e)` and adding `e.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the event handler.

Comment: The `<input>` is of `type` `button`, not `submit`.